# Databases created with different collations - why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, collation

We have a SQL Server 2014 instance, which houses many related databases. New ones are added via our script regularly. When our app is used to create the database - the databases are created with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`  as expected.

But there are now databases with `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation. They were not created by our app (we looked at the database creator). For example, "Pete" is the db owner and some DBs he created would have `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation and others `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Can anyone point out what I could investigate please - should the default collation not always be the same as the SQL instance?
What if I created a database remotely - from PC1 with Collation1 and PC2 with Collation2 - would the database be created with different collations?

Any ideas how this could happen - multiple collations for one user?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `COLLATE` clause of `CREATE DATABASE` can be used to specify a collation different from the Default Server collation.  Also, if the databases were backed up from another server, they would be restored with the collation they had on the source server.

If they are created using `CREATE DATABASE` and a collation is not specified via the `COLLATE` keyword, then the default collation would be used.

Comment: Good. I would also mention that it is also possible, even if unlikely to be the issue here, that the DB default Collation can be changed via `ALTER DATABASE`.